# PyQT5. Как при выбранных уловиях включить QRadioButton элементы в окне?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qradiobutton

Есть небольшой интрфейс **`4`** `QRadioButton` и строка `QLineEdit` с кнопкой для выбора файла.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 181)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.box_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 581, 61))
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("box_selectfile_VT")
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_selectfile_VT)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 561, 31))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 25))
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { padding-left: 5px }")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setText("")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setReadOnly(True)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("QlE_selectfile_VT")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.QlE_selectfile_VT)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("btn_selectfile_VT")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_selectfile_VT)
        self.box_elevB = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_elevB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 201, 70))
        self.box_elevB.setObjectName("box_elevB")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_elevB)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 88, 19))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.elevB_Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.elevB_Yes.setChecked(False)
        self.elevB_Yes.setObjectName("elevB_Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.elevB_Yes)
        self.elevB_No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.elevB_No.setChecked(True)
        self.elevB_No.setObjectName("elevB_No")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.elevB_No)
        self.box_elevPAST = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_elevPAST.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 180, 70))
        self.box_elevPAST.setObjectName("box_elevPAST")
        self.layoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_elevPAST)
        self.layoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 88, 19))
        self.layoutWidget_4.setObjectName("layoutWidget_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.elevPAS_Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setChecked(True)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setObjectName("elevPAS_Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.elevPAS_Yes)
        self.elevPAS_No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.elevPAS_No.setObjectName("elevPAS_No")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.elevPAS_No)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Bitterlich v0.2"))
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите файл"))
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.box_elevB.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие 1"))
        self.elevB_Yes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ДА"))
        self.elevB_No.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕТ"))
        self.box_elevPAST.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие 2"))
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ДА"))
        self.elevPAS_No.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕТ"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Помогите реализовать такой функционал, чтобы при выборе в двух `QRadioButton` условияй "Нет" включался (становился активным) другой элемент (выбор файла).
И если совсем заморачиваться, чтобы это работало в реальном времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виджет `QRadioButton` предоставляет переключатель с текстовой меткой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важные унаследованные члены:

```
text(), setText(), text(), setDown(), isDown(), autoRepeat(), group(), 
setAutoRepeat(), toggle(), pressed(), released(), clicked() и toggled().
```

Подключитесь к сигналу, например `clicked()` если вы хотите запускать действие каждый раз,
когда кнопка активирована (т.е.нажата и отпущена, когда курсор мыши находится внутри кнопки).

Используйте `isChecked()`, чтобы узнать, выбрана ли конкретная кнопка.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 181)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.box_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 581, 61))
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("box_selectfile_VT")
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_selectfile_VT)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 561, 31))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget_3)
#        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 25))
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { padding-left: 5px }")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setText("")
#        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setReadOnly(True)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("QlE_selectfile_VT")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.QlE_selectfile_VT)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
#        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("btn_selectfile_VT")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_selectfile_VT)
        self.box_elevB = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_elevB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 201, 70))
        self.box_elevB.setObjectName("box_elevB")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_elevB)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 88, 19))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.elevB_Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.elevB_Yes.setChecked(False)
        self.elevB_Yes.setObjectName("elevB_Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.elevB_Yes)
        self.elevB_No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.elevB_No.setChecked(True)
        self.elevB_No.setObjectName("elevB_No")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.elevB_No)
        self.box_elevPAST = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_elevPAST.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 180, 70))
        self.box_elevPAST.setObjectName("box_elevPAST")
        self.layoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_elevPAST)
        self.layoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 88, 19))
        self.layoutWidget_4.setObjectName("layoutWidget_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.elevPAS_Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setChecked(True)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setObjectName("elevPAS_Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.elevPAS_Yes)
        self.elevPAS_No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.elevPAS_No.setObjectName("elevPAS_No")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.elevPAS_No)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Bitterlich v0.2"))
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите файл"))
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.box_elevB.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие 1"))
        self.elevB_Yes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ДА"))
        self.elevB_No.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕТ"))
        self.box_elevPAST.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие 2"))
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ДА"))
        self.elevPAS_No.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕТ"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):               
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self) 

        self.elevB_Yes.clicked.connect(self.showCarnot)
        self.elevB_No.clicked.connect(self.showCarnot)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.clicked.connect(self.showCarnot)
        self.elevPAS_No.clicked.connect(self.showCarnot)
        
    def showCarnot(self):
        if self.elevB_No.isChecked() and self.elevPAS_No.isChecked():
            self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 181)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icon.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.box_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 581, 61))
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("box_selectfile_VT")
        self.layoutWidget_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_selectfile_VT)
        self.layoutWidget_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 561, 31))
        self.layoutWidget_3.setObjectName("layoutWidget_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 25))
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { padding-left: 5px }")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setText("")
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setReadOnly(True)
        self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("QlE_selectfile_VT")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.QlE_selectfile_VT)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget_3)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setObjectName("btn_selectfile_VT")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.btn_selectfile_VT)
        self.box_elevB = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_elevB.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 10, 201, 70))
        self.box_elevB.setObjectName("box_elevB")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_elevB)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 88, 19))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.elevB_Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.elevB_Yes.setChecked(False)
        self.elevB_Yes.setObjectName("elevB_Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.elevB_Yes)
        self.elevB_No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.elevB_No.setChecked(True)
        self.elevB_No.setObjectName("elevB_No")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.elevB_No)
        self.box_elevPAST = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.box_elevPAST.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 10, 180, 70))
        self.box_elevPAST.setObjectName("box_elevPAST")
        self.layoutWidget_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.box_elevPAST)
        self.layoutWidget_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 30, 88, 19))
        self.layoutWidget_4.setObjectName("layoutWidget_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.elevPAS_Yes = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setChecked(True)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setObjectName("elevPAS_Yes")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.elevPAS_Yes)
        self.elevPAS_No = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.layoutWidget_4)
        self.elevPAS_No.setObjectName("elevPAS_No")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.elevPAS_No)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # Подключаем вызов метода
        self.elevB_Yes.toggled.connect(self.btnstate)
        self.elevPAS_Yes.toggled.connect(self.btnstate)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Bitterlich v0.2"))
        self.box_selectfile_VT.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Выберите файл"))
        self.btn_selectfile_VT.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выбрать"))
        self.box_elevB.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие 1"))
        self.elevB_Yes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ДА"))
        self.elevB_No.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕТ"))
        self.box_elevPAST.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Условие 2"))
        self.elevPAS_Yes.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ДА"))
        self.elevPAS_No.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "НЕТ"))

    def btnstate(self):
        """
        Проверяет состояние QRadioButton и изменяет QLE/box/btn
        """
        if not self.elevB_Yes.isChecked() and not self.elevPAS_Yes.isChecked():
            self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(True)
            self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(True)
            self.btn_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.box_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
            self.QlE_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)
            self.btn_selectfile_VT.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```